# Jqplot is working in Firefox but showing blank page in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, webkit, jqplot

I have used jqplot and build a graph with use of jQuery and Javascript
http://server.dotsquares.com/cstik/chart.html
which is working fine with Firefox but not showing anything in safari [*edit Marcel K.*: neither in Chrome].
please suggest me what extra code should i place to make it done.

Thanks

Comment: In Chrome, I get an “Uncaught TypeError: Object #<a Document> has no method 'load'” on line 99 of chart.html (which reads `xmlDoc.load("xmldata/wfc20100915.xml");`)

Comment: @Marcle: thanks. please tell me what should i do to make it run in safari.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I am having this problem now and can't find out what is happening. There seems to be on one with similar problems except you, did you ever fix it? and if so how?